# Sum Values not equal to a space from a Control Source in MS Access

Tags: ms-access

As the subject expresses, I'm trying to sum the values of a string field where spaces may exist. It must be done this way, unfortunately.

The database is very old.  The original developer chose to make all fields `Text` fields; to get over the null value problems, a function was written in VB6 to replace any null value with a space. This cannot be changed.

Fast forward to now, I'm trying to create a report that sums the `length` field *without changing spaces to nulls first*, and it should be done entirely through the control source property of the report.

I've added some of what I've tried below, but every time the report is run, I receive:

> Data Type Mismatch

...and I'm not sure how to get around it.

Ideally, I'd like to keep the users out of the database completely, and just add a combo box that lists the reports created in the database so they can be opened by name without having to run any additional update queries first.

```sql
=Sum(IIf([MY_LEN]<>" ",DCount("[MY_LEN]","MY_TABLE"),0))
```

```sql
=Sum(Nz(Iif(Trim([MY_LEN])='',Null,[MY_LEN]),0))
```

```sql
=DSum("[MY_LEN]","[MY_TABLE]","[MY_LEN]<>' '")
```

```sql
=Sum(Iif(Val([MY_LEN])>0,[MY_LEN],0))
```

```sql
=(SELECT Sum([MY_LEN]) AS MyLen FROM MY_TABLE WHERE (((MY_TABLE.[MY_LEN])<>' ')))
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Problem with IIf() in Access is that all parts must be able to be evaluated. What 'null value' problems? Access doesn't retain a single space and drops trailing spaces in fields so what you might end up with is an empty string. I NEVER allow empty string in fields, I prefer Null.

Comment: 'Null Value Problems'... meaning as the developer parsed through recordsets (DAO), if a null value was found there would be a null runtime error... I think 'Invalid Use of Null'.  As a work-around, a wrapper function surrounds every place in the .exe where values are assigned from the database that change null values to a single space.

Comment: I handle Null with Nz() or IsNull() in code but table still has Null field.

Comment: I agree, that would have been a much simpler option for a bunch of reasons.  At least null values are not considered in Count, Sum, etc.  Now I'm faced with change spaces to nulls before using those functions and it's causing a real headache

Comment: Are you sure there is space in field? Because when I try to type a single space in table field, it disappears and I am left with Null field.

Comment: Positive... the space has to be added with code. It won't allow it when it's simply typed...  It may also be possible via a query (Update to ' ' where Is Null)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't compare anything to Null. Can't say `If x = Null Then` because Null is undefined. So you can't test if `undefined = undefined`. Use `If IsNull(x) Then` in VBA and `Is Null` in query criteria. Don't really need IIf() for Sum() aggregate, other aggregates such as Count or Avg would.

To handle possible space, empty string, or Null for a text field holding numeric data.

`=Sum(Val([MY_LEN] & ""))`

Comment: No Sir... thanks for trying though.  I get the same 'Data Type Mismatch Error'.  I had to change your expression a bit (parenthesis), but still no good.  Here's what I tried

=Sum(IIf([MY_LEN]<>' ', Val([MY_LEN]), Null))

Comment: Here is the update query that has to be run first... if the query is run, the report has no problems.

UPDATE MY_TABLE SET MY_TABLE.MY_LEN = Null
WHERE (((MY_TABLE.MY_LEN)=" "));

Comment: Oh, you are replacing space with Null in table. I thought you were dealing with space in the aggregate expression. See edited answer. All tested and work for me.

Comment: I am dealing with the space in the aggregate.  I'm replacing the space with null in an update query in order to get the report to run now, but that's just a band-aid to figure out what is going on.  So far it's lead me here.  I don't want to run the query first.  The function should work and sum the contents of MY_LEN with spaces and values alike.  Due to the method used by the OD, none of the fields in any of the tables are ever null... all empty cells are really spaces.

Comment: I created a test database, if that helps, but I'm not sure where I would put it...

It's simply one table with 10 rows, 2 columns, two queries (one to create spaces from nulls, and one to create nulls from spaces, and a report to sum it all)... it at least verifies the fail.

Comment: So are you going to UPDATE back to space? As I said, I tested expressions and I get correct results for the Sum. Interesting thing, when I filter for empty string, the record with a space is returned. Cannot attach files, could put a link in question to a fileshare download although even that is discouraged here. Or go to another forum site that allows file uploads.

Comment: If you try to run the report as is it will be successful.  To test the error, run the 'MakeSpace' query and try again... you'll get the Data Type Mismatch error

Comment: Ran the MakeSpace query, edited textbox expression to: `=Sum(Val([My_Len]))`. No errors, report runs. Since this is Sum() the IIf isn't really needed.

Comment: You're right, I have no errors in the test database, but it's still not working in the live DB... 
Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188843/discussion-between-runninthrulife-and-june7).

Comment: I gave up on the report, copied it as a new, and deleted everything in it except for the values I was looking for... ran the report and it worked fine.  There must be another value in the report somewhere that needs the same function.  The hunt begins.

The =Sum(Val([My_Len])) function was the correct approach.  A bit aggravating considering that's where I started 4 hours ago.  I didn't dumb it down quick enough.  Thanks for helping me see it through.  I've marked your answer.